# Enable flash player audio access in safari for a website permanently

Tags: audio, security, defaults, adobe-flash

I get this request every time I try to use the microphone on the same web page. Is there anyway to set this so it stops asking for this domain. I understand the security ramifications; however I believe I can trust the site.

It would be nice to access this page without having to answer this on every entry on the page.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash has a control panel is system preferences that you can make these settings changes.

In my version (admittedly older) there is a tab for "Camera and Mic" where you can manage camera and microphone settings by site/

Comment: I spent so much time looking in Safari's preferences that it didn't strike me to check the Sys Prefs. I'm embarrassed at this considering how long I've been a Mac user (and dev) Thanks.Big plus 1 and thanks.